# Reading from std::cin produces Linker error

Tags: c++, linker, std, fastcgi

I have a rather unusual problem. I am trying to do this:

```
char *content = new char[10000];
std::cin.read(content, 10000);
```

And I get the following linker error (weird because the code was compiling fine a few weeks ago, and it hasn't been modified):

```
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::read(char *,__int64)" (__imp_?read@?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@PAD_J@Z) main.obj
```

I verified that I have all the required dependencies linked in the Project Properties, verified that I have /MT set, and the like. The project was compiling fine just a few weeks ago-- the only thing I have done between then and now is update VS2012. Here are my includes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <process.h>
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    extern char ** environ;
#endif

#include "fcgio.h"
#include "fcgi_config.h"

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
```

Comment: Check the project settings to see if it's configured to ignore the default libraries.

Comment: As far as I can see, your includes don't include `iostream`. Either that, or you are using `gcc` instead of `g++` to compile your code.

Comment: does your file end with a '.c'. Seems like the C compiler has been invoked to compile your program.

Comment: Your `read` function call has an error. It should be `std::cin.read(content, 10000);` without the asterisk in front of the `content` parameter.

Comment: I appreciate the help guys. It's not ignoring the default libs, including iostream didn't work, and the file ends with .h. I'm at such a loss.

Comment: I didn't have that error in the code, it was a typo when copying it over. Good eye! No luck yet

Answer (score 0):

It appears that after updating Visual Studio 2012, the project (somehow) became non-functional. Copying the exact same code over to a new project has fixed the problem.